# Does the wave operator preserve smoothness?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, functional-calculus

Let $D:L^2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be a densely defined, first-order elliptic differential operator that is essentially self-adjoint. Then for each $t\geq 0$, one can define the functional calculus operator $e^{itD}$, which is bounded $L^2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I have seen it said that $e^{itD}$ is the *solution operator* for the differential equation $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}=iDu$. This seems to imply that for any compactly supported smooth $u\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, the function $e^{itD}u$ is also smooth. But I cannot see why this is true.

**Question:** In the above situation, is $e^{itD}u$ always smooth and why?

Comment: What do you mean by first-order elliptic? In your question you have to distinguish between smoothness in time and smoothness in space. Operator groups are usually always smooth in time and for example elliptic second order operators do also smooth in space (for arbitrary input), but for example the transport group which is induced by -i d/dx has no smoothing in space.

Comment: I meant to ask if $e^{itD} u$ is smooth in space.